# MongoDB aggregate: retrieve data in single array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have millions of documents with the following schema:

```
{
   _id: '3fbwehgzgfwehgrqwegrqwer',
   someData: [0,1],
   moreData: {
       key: true
   } 
},

{
   _id: '24nj5h219ebwjfqwverqwer',
   someData: [2,3],
   moreData: {
       key: true
   } 
},
```

I need the someData array combined in a result array like:

```
{
    result: [
       [0,1],
       [2,3] 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), you can `$group` by `_id: null`, than `$push` all `$someData` in `result` field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group":{_id: null, result: {$push: "$someData"}}} 
]).pretty()
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "result" : [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ] ] }
```